# Handle shortcut key event from keyboard in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

My code is:

```
if(mBooleanLoginDone==true)
{
    mMenuItemProdType.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.T, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN, KeyCodeCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
}
else
{
   System.out.println("Not Loggged In");
}
```

In Above code mBooleanLoginDone is a Boolean variable indicating where the user logged in or not. I want shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to work only when user successfully logged in but right now I'm not logged in and shortcut key is also working. How can I solve it any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(mBooleanLoginDone==true)
{
    mMenuItemProdType.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.T, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN, KeyCodeCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN));
}
else
{
   mMenuItemProdType.setAccelerator(null);
   System.out.println("Not Loggged In");
}
```